# $\text{sign}(x)$ and one-sided Lipschitz

Tags: lipschitz-functions

We say that a function $f:R^2\longrightarrow R$ satisfies one-sided Lipschitz condition with respect to x with constant $K$ if 
$$\langle f(x_{1},y)-f(x_{2},y),x_{1}-x_{2}\rangle \leq K||x_{1}-x_{2}||^2.$$
And my question is how can we check if this these functions $f(x,y)=-\text{sign}(x)$ $f(x,y)=\text{sign}(x)$ satisfy one-sided Lipschitz condition or not.

Comment: Did you try computing the left side?

Comment: it is $f(x,y)=\text{sign}(x)$

Comment: @J.Mccain, then what purpose does $y$ serve here?

Comment: @YuriyS, in this function y does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. A useful approximation is this: $$\text{sign} (x)=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+t^2}}$$

Do you see how to  continue?

Or you can just consider the two cases.

First: $$\text{sign} (x_1)=\text{sign} (x_2) \\ | \text{sign} (x_1)-\text{sign} (x_2)|=0$$

Second: $$\text{sign} (x_1)=-\text{sign} (x_2) \\ | \text{sign} (x_1)-\text{sign} (x_2)|=2$$

Do you see how to continue here?

Comment: not really, I don't

Comment: @J.Mccain, see my edit

Comment: thanks, but why did we start with considering $\text{sign}(x_{1})=\text{sign}(x_{2})$

Comment: @J.Mccain what is $\text{sign(x)}$? What is this function, which values does it take?

Comment: it takes -1 , 0 , +1

Comment: oh!... ok I got it... thanks